# If not go through TMG get error

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, ntlm

We have a custom web service hosted in sharepoint 2013 foundation. It works fine if in client's host files we add this,

```
web service url...   //go to TMG ip address e.g.  10.0.0.100
```

But when we remove this from client's host files we get error,

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

We are using basicHttpBinding with following settings,

```
 BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
 binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
```

We can still solve the problem by pointing client to go through Microsoft TMG Fore front server first before going to server which is hosting our custom wcf service.

But now we are planning to move hosted wcf service to AZURE and not sure how TMG going to interact with AZURE's box.

Why is this behaviour and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

The error means that your WCF service required basic(user name and password) authentication but your client passed Windows NTLM Negotiate ticket. If you configure the TMG IP in your host file, TMG will work as an [ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/active-directory-federation-services) proxy. You must have an internal ADFS infrastructure setup and connected to Office 365 already. TMG will authenticate the request and pass the result to your WCF service.

> But now we are planning to move hosted wcf service to AZURE and not sure how TMG going to interact with AZURE's box.

After moved to Azure, you can also use Azure PaaS to create virtual machines and installed any software on it. But it is not recommended. Azure Active Directory Application Proxy could provide ADFS Integration feature which is the [recommended way](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/applicationproxyblog/2015/07/02/transitioning-to-application-proxy-from-uag-and-tmg/) to replace TMG on Azure. For how to use Azure Active Directory Application Proxy, link below is for your reference.

[How to provide secure remote access to on-premises applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-get-started)